# Get files with same/ similar name from array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have multiple objects in an array of which the format:

> id_name_date_filetype.

I need to take all the objects with, let's say same id or same name and insert them in a new array. 
With the `GetFiles` method I already have all the object in one array and I have their names but I don't know how to differentiate them. 
I have a `foreach` I which I'll be going through all the objects but I'm kind of stuck. 
Any hints as to what do I do?

```
//Process the files
string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory, "*.tsv*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(filename => Path.GetFullPath(filename)).Distinct().ToArray();

foreach (string file in filelist)
{
    string[] fileNameSplit = file.Split('_');
    switch (fileNameSplit.Last().ToLower())
    {
        case "assets.tsv":
            assets = ReadDataFromCsv<Asset>(file);
            break;
        case "financialaccounts.tsv":
            financialAccounts = ReadDataFromCsv<FinancialAccount>(file);
            break;
        case "households.tsv":
            households = ReadDataFromCsv<Household>(file);
            break;
        case "registrations.tsv":
            registrations = ReadDataFromCsv<Registration>(file);
            break;
        case "representatives.tsv":
            representatives = ReadDataFromCsv<Representative>(file);
            break;
    }
}

// Find all files from one firm and insert them in a list
foreach (string file in filelist)
{

}
```

Comment: first hint: please post the code, it is usually easier to understand than a description of it.

Comment: basically you would split each file name by `_` and then filter according to the position depending on what you want to compare like this: `certainIDArray = yourArray.Where(x=>x.Split('_')[0] == "yourID").ToArray();`

Comment: I added the code, thank you for your fast input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a linq approach as I proposed it in my comment:

First get all distinct ID's from your filelist

```
string [] allDistinctIDs = filelist.Select(x=>x.Split('_').First()).Distinct(). ToArray();
```

now you can iterate through the list of ID's and compare each value

```
for (int i = 0; i < allDistinctIDs.Length; i++)
{
    string [] allSameIDStrings = filelist.Where(x=>x.Split('_').First() == allDistinctIDs[i]).ToArray();    
}
```

Basically you split every item by `'_'` and compare the first (id part) of the string with each item from your  list of distinct ID's.

Another approach would be to use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
// example input
string[] filelist = {
    "123_Name1_xxx_Asset.tsv", 
    "456_Name2_xxx_Asset.tsv", 
    "123_Name3_xxx_HouseHold.tsv", 
    "456_Name4_xxx_HouseHold.tsv"};

IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> ID_Groups = filelist.GroupBy(x=>x.Split('_').First());
```

This would give you a collection of all filenames grouped by the ID:

[image]

at each position in `ID_Groups` is a list of items with the same ID. You can filter them by fileName:

```
foreach (var id_group in ID_Groups)
{
    assets = ReadDataFromCsv<Asset>(id_group.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ToLower().Contains("assets.tsv")));
    // and so on
    households = ReadDataFromCsv<Household>(id_group.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ToLower().Contains("households.tsv")));
}
```

Comment: But I can't compare the first part of the string to anything because I don't know what I am looking for in the beginning.
Basically I have 200+ files in a folder. I get them and insert them in an array. Then I need to take all the ones with the same ID or same name and put those in an array.

Comment: so you want to filter out all duplicate ID's and put them in separate lists ?=! did I get you this time?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as it put me on the right track.

Comment: @NovicaJosifovski I added a group by approach. You can decide which one suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta define what is "Similar" to you. It could be the initial letter of the file name? Half of it? Whole filename?

This function should do more or less what you want without using Linq or something more complex than loops.

```
var IDOffileNameIWant = object.GetFiles()[0].id;
List<string> arrayThatContainsSimilar = new List<string>();
 
foreach(var file in object.GetFiles())
{
    
    if(file.Name.Split('_')[0].Contains(IDOffileNameIWant))
    {
        arrayThatContainsSimilar.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

It's very basic and can be refined, but you gotta give more details on what is the exact result you want to obtain.

Since you're still struggling, here's a working example:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>() {
    "123_novica_file1", "123_novica_file3", "123_novica_file2", "456_myfilename_file1",
    "789_myfilename_file1", "101_novica_file2", "102_novica_file3"};

List<string> filesbyID = new List<string>();
List<string> filesbyName = new List<string>();

string theIDPattern = "123";
string theFileNamePattern = "myfilename";

foreach(var file in files)
{
    //splitting the filename and checking by ID
    if(file.Split('_')[0].Contains(theIDPattern))
    {
        filesbyID.Add(file);
    }

    //splitting the filename and checking by name
    if (file.Split('_')[1].Contains(theFileNamePattern))
    {
        filesbyName.Add(file);
    }
}
```

Result:

files by id:

> 123_novica_file1
>
> 123_novica_file3
>
> 123_novica_file2

files by name:

> 456_myfilename_file1
>
> 789_myfilename_file1

Comment: The id will be the same, as well as the name. I was planning on differentiating the objects by id as perhaps that's smartest? What do you think?

Comment: @MongZhu true that. It was a quick example to fiddle with

Comment: @NovicaJosifovski I've modified the code. It's just a quick example, try to fiddle with it. Basically you should split the file name with the _ characther and get the element [0] for the id, [1] for the name and use Contains on each file and add them to an array with the file names. Sounds good?

Comment: @LiquidCore  
the thing is, the format is id_name_date_filetype but the id will most likely be three or more numbers, something like 123_novica_date_filetype. I too think splitting the name at the '_' is smart in my situation but i am still lost as to how get the id in order to separate the files with different ids.

Comment: @NovicaJosifovski I gave you a working example. Mark as answer if it helped.

Comment: I can't compare the files like that because at any given moment I don't know what the ID or the name is.

Comment: @NovicaJosifovski You have 2 options, or you take the id from time to time with the split or you have to know it beforehand. As I've already said you have to specify a pattern before, otherwise it's impossible to do what you ask. How can I know if in you file names all the id are different or for example if you want to take all the ids starting with 10?